# generate 2 random files 500MB with some common lines

Tags: command-line

(Hi!)

I need to generate 2 files (each file must be 500 MB). And those 2 files should have some common lines (but not necessary at the same place in the file)

I was thinking about something like that: `cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-f0-9' | fold -w 32 | head -n 30000000 > random.csv` but it's not exactly what I want to do ...

can you suggest me something ?

Comment: What does it mean if a "file should do 500Mo"?

Comment: @mook765 It means 500 MB (mega octects in French).

Comment: the file must be 500 MB, sorry

Comment: With what you already have, you can generate 2 files of approximately the right size. Then you generate a third (smaller) file which you append to the 2 files. With the `shuf` command you may shuffle your 2 files and you have some common lines somewhere in the files. (However I have no idea how much time or space a shuffle of such huge files will take - I would try with some more reasonable size.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my suggestion from the comment in form of a smaller example:

```
    # generate the 2 basic files of 30 lines each
cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-f0-9' | fold -w 32 | head -n 30 > random1.csv
cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-f0-9' | fold -w 32 | head -n 30 > random2.csv
    # generate 3 common lines
cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-f0-9' | fold -w 32 | head -n 3 > common.csv
    # mix the common lines into the 2 files
cat random1.csv common.csv | shuf > random11.csv
cat random2.csv common.csv | shuf > random22.csv
```

Verifying:

```
$ cat common.csv
8b1df61042e621bb3cd3ba43942b5ada
71b2368e90c6eb038e84ef29446c0dec
56697847ec43cc181a556625ec880d85
    # select one common line and look for it in the 2 files
$ grep -n 71b2368e90c6eb038e84ef29446c0dec random11.csv random22.csv
random11.csv:13:71b2368e90c6eb038e84ef29446c0dec
random22.csv:9:71b2368e90c6eb038e84ef29446c0dec
```

So one of the common lines is line #13 in the first file and line #9 in the second file.

But beware of the needed resources if you take 30M lines instead of 30!

Comment: why random11 and random22 ?

Comment: Name them as you like, but you can't take random1 and random2, because the output file is reset before reading the input.